# NodeJS throws Illegal instruction: 4 on Mac OS

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, npm

Whenever I run my program it throws Illegal instruction: 4 and I have no idea why.

My code:

```
glob('/path/music/*.mp3', function(error, files) {
for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    songs.push(files[i]);
    console.log("Added file: " + files[i]);
}

console.log("Init player");
p = new player(songs)
    .on('playing', function(song){
        console.log("Playing now: " + song._name);
    })
    .on('playend', function(song){
        console.log("Next song....");
    })
    .on('error', function(song){
        console.log("Error:" + error);
    }).play();

    setTimeout(function(){ p.stop();},5000);


    console.log(JSON.stringify(p))
});
```

So the program should play a mp3 file from my path for 5 seconds and stop it after that but after it plays for 5 seconds the program terminates and the console output is:

```
> node script.js
Playing now: music.mp3
Illegal instruction: 4
```

I'm using the player package from npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/player

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the [speaker npm module](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-speaker) in [player npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/player).

I found the following issue in the speaker GitHub repo ["OSX - Illegal Instruction:4"](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-speaker/issues/95)

The solution was to update speaker in node_modules/speaker:

```
npm install speaker --mpg123-backend=openal
```

*(I also updated lame to version 1.2.4, which you may need to do as well)*

Lastly, I rebuilt the bin in the player module

```
npm run build
```

Here's the code I used to test/debug:

```
const glob = require('glob');
const player = require('player');

glob('*.mp3', (error, files) => {
  console.log("Init player");
  const p = new player(files);

  p.on('playing', function(song){
      console.log("Playing now: " + song._name);
  })
  .on('playend', function(song){
      console.log("Next song....");
  })
  .on('error', function(song){
      console.log("Error:" + error);
  });

  p.play();

  setTimeout(function(){
    p.next();
  }, 2000);
});
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you're using binary add-ons that were compiled for a different system or architecture.

You can try running `npm rebuild` or `npm install` in your app's directory.

You can also remove the `node_modules` and run `npm install` from scratch.

If that doesn't help then it may be a bug with some of the modules that you're using or maybe it doesn't support your architecture, or maybe some library that is used by that module were not installed on your system properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
npm uninstall player --save
npm uninstall speaker --save
npm install player --mpg123-backend=openal
```

And it worked for me.